# Why are is SetIndex of a SharedArray complaining with Immutable types?

Tags: types, casting, multiprocessing, julia, shared-memory

So I have a very simple problem. I have a type defined as the following:

```
# An internal type used only by the train function for caching between epochs.
immutable Residual
    value::Float32
    curr_error::Float32
    prev_error::Float32
end
```

I am working on a machine learning algorithm in Julia and want to break by checking these values at the end of @parrellel loops. To achieve this, I am using SharedArrays defined like so.

```
residuals = SharedArray(Residual, size(rating_set.training_set), init = S -> S[Base.localindexes(S)] = [Residual(rating.value, 0.0, 0.0) for rating in rating_set.training_set[Base.localindexes(S)]])
```

Now, inside the loop, I want to update the residual with a simple update steps. Since it's immutable, I assume I have to create a new Residual object and stuff it in the SharedArray.

```
residual[j] = Residual(residual.value, -user_feature * item_feature + residual.value, residual.curr_error)
```

However, whenever I run the code I get the following error.

```
LoadError: MethodError: `setindex!` has no method matching setindex!(::Residual, ::Residual, ::Int64)
```

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong, I assume it has something to do with typing? Or am I just completely misunderstanding SharedArrays in Julia? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this was embarrassing, I left off an s in the array so it tried to the set the index on the immutable type... I'll leave this question up here in case anyone else makes the same mistake.